# How to find result of system $x+y^2-4=0$ and $y+x^2-4=0$ without using the quartic formula

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

How do I get the values of $x$ and $y$, without using the quartic formula?

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases} x+y^2-4=0 \\ y+x^2-4=0  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 8):

Subtract the first equation from the second to obtain:
$$x^2-y^2+y-x=0\Leftrightarrow \\
(x-y)(x+y-1)=0 $$

Comment: thank you very much , how you figured out to  factor by (x-y) ?

Comment: @AndriNic Because $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ is a basic identity: difference of 2 squares

Comment: then from here $(x-y)(x+y)+y-x = 0 $ how do i simplify more?

Comment: @AndriNic $y-x=-(x-y)$, then you can see $x-y$ is a factor.

Comment: thank you , i been a lot of time figuring out how to solve it